# spring MVC, get the value of the rejected field from ObjectError

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-validator

I have already check the similar questions on so but I don't have anything matching.

I check if I have errors with:

```
result.getErrorCount() != 0)
```

and inside I have the list of errors using

```
List<ObjectError> ae = result.getAllErrors();
```

when I use the debug mode of eclipse and I check the field inside the list I have the good id in the form.
But at runtime I'm unable to get the value by doing

```
for (ObjectError fe : result.getAllErrors())
{
   fe.getField();           
}
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You need to cast `ObjectError` to `FieldError` and then you can retrieve the name of the affected field by calling `getField()`.

[JavaDoc for FieldError](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/validation/FieldError.html)

Comment: Thank you, I'm pretty new to java and eclipse so I take the default stuff that give me eclipse :/